# laravel whereArray type method

Tags: php, laravel

I'm wondering if there is an eloquent method which I can pass the where method an array. For example

I have an array of query params like so:

```
[
    "limit" => "4"
    "is_completed" => "true"
    "status" => 1
]
```

So I can just pass in:

`$this->model->whereArray($queryParams)->get();`

and that `whereArray` method just loops through each query param and would do something similar to this:

```
foreach($queryParam as $param => $key)
{
    $this->where($param, '=', $key);

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can do the following.

```
$this->model->where([
    "limit" => "4",
    "is_completed" => "true",
    "status" => 1,
])->get();
```

Above will use `and` by default to join the `wheres`. If you need to override that behavior you can pass a fourth parameter.

```
$this->model->where([
    "limit" => "4",
    "is_completed" => "true",
    "status" => 1,
], null, null, 'or')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion I will use a query scope to make my codes more modular. In Eloquent's query scope provided you have a model, you will use

```
    public function scopeFilter($query) {
    $query->where('param1', 'operator', 'value1')
            ->where('param2', 'operator', 'value2')
            ->where('param3', 'operator', 'value3')
            ->where('param4', 'operator', 'value4');
}
```

After specifying the query scope in your model, you then call it just like a function in your controller.

```
$this->model->filter()->get();
```

And you are good to go. Don't forget to change the operator to something useful and the naming convention for the scope is **Camel Case**.